# Merge classification and detection Model onnx

Tags: classification, detection, yolo, onnx, yolov5

im trying to Merge two models
first one is a detection model and i would like to feed detected object to a classifier model
both model traind by yolov5 and converted to onnx , i need an onnx model that get an image and use both models to detect and classify object

note:i know i can directly classfiy and detecte object using detection model but i prefer to have more accurate model

```
import onnxruntime
import onnx

# Load the detection model and classification model
detection_model =            onnxruntime.InferenceSession('exp2/weights/best.onnx')
classification_model =   onnxruntime.InferenceSession('runs/exp18/weights/best.onnx')

# Get the input and output nodes of both models
detection_input = detection_model.get_inputs()[0].name
detection_output = detection_model.get_outputs()[0].name
classification_input = classification_model.get_inputs()[0].name
classification_output = classification_model.get_outputs()[0].name

#Create a new ONNX model that combines the detection and classification models
node = onnx.helper.make_node('Identity', inputs=[detection_output], outputs=['input_1'])
graph_def = onnx.helper.make_graph([node],
                               'merged_model',
                               inputs=[onnx.helper.make_tensor_value_info('input_1',             onnx.TensorProto.FLOAT, [1, 3, 384, 384])],
                               outputs=  [onnx.helper.make_tensor_value_info(classification_output, onnx.TensorProto.FLOAT, [1, 11])])
model_def = onnx.helper.make_model(graph_def, producer_name='onnx-example')

# Create a new InferenceSession with the combined model
combined_model = onnxruntime.InferenceSession(model_def.SerializeToString())`
```